# ¿Cómo excluir un directorio con el comando find?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, búsquedas

Estoy buscando archivos de tipo 'test*' dentro de un repositorio. Dado que tengo un virtualenv, cada vez que hago `find -name 'test*'` me encuentra muchos archivos de los módulos que tengo instalados.

```
find -name 'test*'
```

Devuelve muchas cosas del tipo:

```
./env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paquete/utils/tests
```

¿Cómo puedo excluir un directorio y todo su contenido de los resultados de `find`?

Uso `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2` y todos los intentos de usar `-prune` han sido infructuosos.

Comment: Recibí un voto negativo aquí y en la respuesta. ¿Hay algo que necesite mejora? ¡Gracias por comentar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes utilizar la sintaxis `-not -path` para indicar el directorio a excluir:

```
find -name 'test*' -not -path "./env/*"
```

Nótese que al escribir el directorio debes añadir un asterisco para que interprete que es todo su contenido. Esto es, `find -name 'test*' -not -path "./env/"` solo excluirá el directorio, mientras que `"./env/*"` excluirá todo su contenido (recursivamente).

Como siempre, recuerda que la opción `-type` te permite restringir por tipo: archivo, directorio... Por ejemplo, esto buscará solamente los archivos:

```
find -type f -name 'test*' -not -path "./env/*"
```

Referencia: [Exclude directory from find . command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15736463/1983854)